# Return an extra argument with the datachart

Tags: django, django-templates, nvd3.js

I'm trying to print a chart and to return an argument with the datachart to the template.

Views.py:

```
def errors(request):
    totalErrors = total_errors()
    table = table_errors()
    return render_to_response('macaco_errores.djhtml', {'totalErrors': totalErrors, 'table': table})
```

There's no problem to print the chart without the 'table' argument, but with both I get 'False' in template when I load in "load_chart".

EDIT:
Template:

```
{% block head %}
    {% load nvd3_tags %}
    {% include_chart_jscss %}
    {% load_chart charttype totalesData totalesContainer extra %}   
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div align="center">
    <h1>Errors</h1>
    {% include_container totalesContainer 600 1000 %}
</div>

<div align="center">
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>Log</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
    {% for type,log,date in table.items %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ type }}</td>
    <td>{{ log }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Post the source of your template. It sounds like you are giving bad config to nvd3.js rather than any problem on the Django side

Comment: I edited with the template.

Comment: are you using http://django-nvd3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ ?

Comment: Yes. I'm using latest and I can draw a chart. My problem is that I want to print in a table (inside a template) another variable (dictionary) and when I return two arguments from view it didn't draw.

Answer (score 0):

`{% load_chart charttype totalesData totalesContainer extra %}`

This tag is needing four variables in the context: `charttype`, `totalesData`, `totalesContainer`, `extra`

It appears you are not passing any of them from your view function (which provides only `totalErrors` and `table`)

So there is no way that this can work from the code you've posted.

See this example from the django-nvd3 docs for the type of context data you need to provide from your view function:
http://django-nvd3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html#example-how-to-create-a-piechart

Please see also the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/) for how to pass variables from the view function into the template for rendering.

For example in your view you are currently using the [`render_to_response` helper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response) which takes a dict of variable names and values to pass to the template... these are the *only* vars which are available in the template.

Comment: I know that. In fact, you can pass the variables you want. These variables are configurated in views.py. The focus is return two arguments in render_to_response. If I return only one, for charting, there's no problem.

Comment: if you don't pass the variables from the view the template can't use them

Comment: I have "return render_to_response('macaco_errores.djhtml', {'totalErrors': totalErrors, 'table': table})" in views.py

Comment: yes, but you are not passing the other four variables the tag needs to render a chart

Comment: Thank you Anentropic!!! You give me light. What I did is 'accumulate' all the arguments in only one and in the template access to them.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was:

```
def counterroresmacaco(request):
    errores = errores_macaco()
    errores['tabla'] = tipoerror_ticker()
    return render_to_response('macaco_errores.djhtml', errores)
```

'errores' is a dictionary, then in the template I use a for to iterate over 'tabla'.
The problem to pass two arguments (as I was doing) is that django-nvd3 doesn't recognize the arguments like in the examples.

```
{% load nvd3_tags %}
{% include_chart_jscss %}
{% load_chart charttype totalesData totalesContainer extra %}

{% include_container totalesContainer 600 1000 %}

<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Tipo de log</th>
<th>Ticker</th>
</tr>
{% for reg in tabla %}
<tr>
<td>{{ reg.log }}</td>
<td>{{ reg.ticker }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: You are wrong, the problem was not that you "passed two arguments" (because you didn't: you passed a single argument that was a dictionary, which is correct). The problem was that the `tabla` key was not in your dictionary.

Comment: In the first one I returned two arguments, one called 'table' (I know that is not 'tabla'). Maybe there's more solutions but I had to change from two arguments to add all arguments only in one becase load_chart in template couldn't receive others arguments only can receive a dictionary and you have to configure it in views.py adding the keys 'charttype totalesData totalesContainer extra' and its values.

Comment: The code you have posted bears no relation to what you are saying